# inaccurate statistics in multitenant database

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are using Azure SQL and have "multi tenant" database. All tables have tenantid + entityid pk. Some tenants have a lot of data and some tenants quite small. 
Also auto update statistics is enabled.

Sometimes (quite often recently) after auto update of statistics  we get inaccurate statistics (depending on sample) and according to it tenant has 1 row (but actually 10-100k).
This leads to bad execution plans and performance problem for the whole db.

Maybe somebody has ideas how to fix it.

Comment: Please state what version of SQL Server.  Newer versions update statistics more often, and there is a trace flag you can set on some older versions to use the newer update algorithm.

Comment: we are using azure sql with compatibility level 150, so it should use the latest algorithm

Comment: You may need to update stats manually with a larger sample size than the default.  If the rows it analyzes for the default sample are not indicative of the entire table, then you may need a larger sample size.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion with Azure SQL Database, perform index maintenance during off-hours using Ola Hallengren's scripts and after that update all columns statistics with full scan. Do not rely on automatic features on medium size databases (> 100 GB).

[Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5666/index-maintenance-in-azure-sql-database-with-ola-hallengrens-scripts-and-elastic-database-jobs/) you will find steps to create elastic jobs to update indexes and statistics using Ola Hallengren's scripts.

Another way to perform maintenance of indexes and statistics can be found [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/automating-azure-sql-db-index-and-statistics-maintenance-using/ba-p/368974) using Azure Automation and PowerShell.